# Как разбудить esp32 после DeepSleep?

Tags: arduino, esp32

Подскажите, как разбудить esp32 после глубокого сна по нажатию на кнопку.

```
esp_deep_sleep_start(); // укладываю спать на неопределенное время.
```

И теперь мне необходимо чтобы оно проснулось.

Comment: Через touch пины: https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-touch-wake-up-deep-sleep/. Через external wake up (произвольные RTC_GPIO пины): https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-external-wake-up-deep-sleep/

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось. Правда думаю, что все равно аккумы быстро сядут.